# Reading numbers from a file in C++

Tags: c++

I want to get numbers from a text file by reading it symbol by symbol and output the numbers in another file.

Number - a word which consists only of numeric symbols.

Word - any string of symbols which is separated by dot, comma, brackets, exclamation mark, question mark or line break.

For example from file

### in.txt:

```
masnd kasjd k!1234 564,7
7.,43, mb?? 67hh k4k 87 90.
```

I want to output

### out.txt

```
1234
564
7
7
43
87
90
```

I tried to read the whole word to check if the word is a number, and if it is put the 'cursor' in the beginning of the word and output it in the out.txt

I somewhere messed up and all I get in the out.txt file is

### out.txt

```
234
64

7
87
90
```

And also if I don't put a separating symbol in the end of the in.txt file it stucks in a loop somewhere, and when I close the program and try to open the out.txs file, notepad crushes

This is how far i have made it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
bool isStop(char c);
int main(){
    fstream fin;
    fstream fout;
    streampos p;
    char a,b=' ';
    fin.open("in.txt", ios::in);
    fout.open("out.txt", ios::out);
    fin.get(a);
    while(!fin.eof()){
        if(isdigit(a) && isStop(b)){
            p=fin.tellg();
            while(isdigit(a) && !fin.eof()){
            fin.get(a);
            }
            if(isStop(a) || fin.eof()){
                fin.seekg(p-1, ios::beg);
                fin.get(a);
                while(isdigit(a) && !fin.eof()){
                    fout.put(a);
                    fin.get(a);
                }
                fout.put('\n');
            }
        }
        b=a;
        fin.get(a);
    }
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
bool isStop(char c)
{
    return (c==' ' || c=='.' || c==',' || c=='(' || c==')' || c=='!' ||                             c=='?' || c=='\n');
}
```

Comment: Do not use the test `!fin.eof()`. Instead check for `while(fin.get(a))`

Comment: It appears that your input file has newline characters. Perhaps you could check against `isspace(c)` instead of `c== ' '`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to check the file symbol by symbol so I couldn't use getline, but in the end I figured it all out.

I saved the word in a string and afterwards checked if it was a number and if it was, i put it in the out file.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
bool isStop(char c);
int main(){
    fstream fin;
    fstream fout;
    string s;
    char a,b=' ';
    fin.open("inF20.txt", ios::in);
    fout.open("outF20.txt", ios::out);
    while(fin.get(a)){
        if(isdigit(a) && isStop(b)){
                s+=a;
            while(fin.get(a) && isdigit(a)){
                s+=a;
            }
            if(isStop(a) || fin.eof()){
                for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
                    fout.put(s[i]);
                }
                fout.put('\n');
            }
        }
        s.clear();
        b=a;
    }
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
bool isStop(char c)
{
    return (c==' ' || c=='.' || c==',' || c=='(' || c==')' || c=='!' || c=='?' || c=='\n');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issue stems from a couple of things, like treating the space character as the only whitespace character (when there could be newlines `'\n'`, tabs `'\t'`, or carriage returns `'\r'`), and additionally using `!fin.eof()` as a loop check.

In fact, All the jumping around in the file appears unnecessary and difficult to read.

I propose the following simplified algorithm (much more C++-esque):

- Read a line
- Parse the line into words
- Verify a word is a valid number (according to your rules)
- if valid, write that number to file

Here's one possible implementation (using `cin` and `cout` instead of files):

---

#### Define your separators:

```
const std::string separators = ",.()! \t";
```

#### Read a line:

```
std::string next;
while(getline(std::cin, next))
{
```

#### Break it into words:

```
    std::string::iterator beg = std::begin(next);
    while(beg != std::end(next))
    {
        beg = std::find_if(beg, std::end(next), [](char c)
        {
            return std::isdigit(c);
        });

        std::string::iterator end = std::find_if(beg, std::end(next), [](char c)
        {
            return separators.find(c) != std::string::npos;
        });

        // now we have digit to separator (or end of string). So long as elements between beg (inclusive) and end(exclusive) are all digits, we're good
```

Verify the word is all digits from first digit to next separator:

```
        std::string::iterator it = beg;
        for(; it != end && isdigit(*it); ++it)
        {}
```

#### If verification passes, write to file:

```
        if (it == end) // they're all digits
        {
            std::cout << std::string(beg, end) << std::endl;
        }
        beg = end;
    } // end while loop (word separation)
} // end while loop (reading lines)
```

### [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0566da4b45c2588e)

Comment: Thanks for reply and help, but I had to check the file symbol by  symbol with get. Thanks for advicing to check for while(fin.get(a)) In the end  I figured it all out..

Answer (score 0):

A bit more c++ like:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;
// string of separators 
static const string valid = ".,!? \n\0'";   

// check whether a character is in the separator
static bool isValid(char c) { 
  return (find(valid.begin(), valid.end(), c) != valid.end());
}

int main() {
  // open your input/output files
  ifstream inputf("./in.txt");
  ofstream outf("./out.txt");
  // save your input in a string
  string file((istreambuf_iterator<char>(inputf)), (istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
  int beg; // start of a number (index)
  std::string nb;
  // iterate over your string
  for (int i = 0; i < file.size() ;) {
    // while your char is an alpha char, do nothing
    while (isdigit(file[i]) == false) ++i;
    nb = "";
    beg = i;
    // search for a number
    while (isdigit(file[i]) == true)
      nb += file[i++];
    // check if the current number can be saved in the output file
    if (nb != "" && isValid(file[i]) && (beg == 0 || isValid(file[beg - 1])))
      outf << nb << "\n";
  }
  inputf.close(); outf.close();
}
```

And then your output file:

```
$> cat out.txt 
1234
564
7
7
43
87
90
```